# Oracle WITH AS SELECT with GRANT

Tags: oracle, with-statement, sql-grant

I'm using WITH to create like a temporary table and query upon it. But my SELECT(running on the temp table) has a function call with temp table as the input parameter. **How to give function access to temp table created using WITH.**

```
WITH TEMP_TABLE AS 
(select * from schema1.main_table where col_datetime > sysdate - 4) -- to reduce the data main query executes upon
(
Select * FROM table(schema2.FUNCTION1(blah, blah, 'TEMP_TABLE', blah, blah))
);
```

Error below

```
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06512: at "schema2.FUNCTION1", line 143
ORA-06512: at line 1
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using a Common Table Expression (CTE). A CTE is temporarily created only in the context of the broader query and so the CTE's complete dataset of records are outside of the usable scope of functions. You can use individual values from the CTE and pass to a function but your function cannot see the full CTE. The CTE does not exist in a context accessible by the function.

You may consider posting a separate question describing what you hope to accomplish inside the function and we may be able to give you some pointers on an alternate method that fits the SQL specifications.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Function is implementing big business logic, mainly percentile calculation on huge set of data.

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve here is to optimize the query by making it run on a subset of data instead of running it on the full table. In my actual select query that function is called upon like 9 times to calculate various percentile values. so that means its fetching the record that many times, Instead if I can somehow store the subset of data in like a temp table then it will not have to fetch it every time. Just to mention, actual table size is like 500 GBs

Answer (score 1):

The PL/SQL `WITH` function can directly answer your question.  You can't pass the `WITH` table, but you can use a `WITH` function to create a table, and then reference that table in your existing function.

This code requires Oracle 12.1.  And please be aware of the potential for SQL injection with the names.

```
with
    function create_temp_table return varchar2 is
        pragma autonomous_transaction;
    begin
        execute immediate 'drop table temp_table';
        execute immediate 'create table temp_table as select 2 a, 3 b from dual';
        return 'temp_table';
    end;
select * from table(function1(create_temp_table()))
/
```

Here's the sample schema to make the above SQL work:

```
create or replace type function1_rec is object(a number, b number);
create or replace type function1_nt is table of function1_rec;

create or replace function function1(p_table_name varchar2) return function1_nt is
    v_results function1_nt;
begin
    execute immediate 'select function1_rec(a,b) from '||p_table_name
    bulk collect into v_results;

    return v_results;
end;
/
```

Although I agree with Sam M that you might want to look into alternative methods.  I have a feeling there is a simpler way to accomplish what you're looking for.